# Using jQuery to store href attribute as a new variable

Tags: jquery, html, frontend

I have an anchor tag with id of 'item-1'

`<a id='item-1' href='#something'>`

and I would like to store its `href` attribute in a new variable named 'href.'

How can I accomplish this using jquery?

Comment: Gave a short example to support the text, added a question

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
var href = $('#item-1').attr('href');

console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="test" id="item-1"></a>
```

or in JavaScript use **[`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**

```js
var href = document.getElementById('item-1').getAttribute('href');

console.log(href);
```

```html
<a href="test" id="item-1"></a>
```